# Find the last cell that contains data in column

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I have an excel file that contains the names of the columns in the first row.
How can I find the number of the last non-empty column in the first row?
I use the library ClosedXML.Excel;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook(fileName);
int col = workbook.Worksheet(1)
          .Row(1)
          .LastCellUsed()
          .Address
          .ColumnNumber;
```